# DrawerLayout и Fragment

Tags: java, android

В общем дело обстоит так, мне нужно составить скелет навигации такой же как в вк. Как создать навигационную панель ясно. Я просто взял готовый макет из android studio. Но теперь самое главное. Я подумал что правильно будет сделать так: поставить FrameLayout в разметку главной активности, там где NavigationView и запихивать в этот фрейм фрагменты в зависимости от того что выбрал пользователь в навигацинной панели. Это у меня получилось реализовать, но я столкнулся с главной проблемой. Как мне менять toolbar в зависимости от того в каком фрагменте я нахожусь. И даже если я его смогу поменять, не будет ли это влиять на работоспособность самой выдвижной панели. Возможно я изначально спроектировал что-то не так, поэтому прошу помощи

Comment: А что именно вам менять надо? Заголовок? Пункты меню добавлять? Цвет? Иконку навигации?

Comment: Пункты меню я знаю как менять через фрагмент, но мне нужно вообще полностью кастомизировать тулбар. Где-то поиск встроить, где-то выпадающий список, где то динамический тулбар, примено как в вк

Comment: Ну, у вас два пути - делать всё в фрагменте или из фрагмента вызывать метод актвити...

Comment: каким образом это делать в фрагментах, там же тулбар должен связываться с выдвижной панелью

Comment: Тулбар у вас должен быть в актвити. А фрагменты не должны иметь тулбара